# Parse Schema.org 'openingHours' string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing, schema.org

I want to convert strings like this:

> Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 12:00-18:00, Sa 12:00-16:00

to text like this:

```
Monday     12:00-18:00
Tuesday    12:00-18:00
Wednesday  12:00-18:00
Thursday   12:00-18:00
Friday     12:00-18:00
Saturday   12:00-16:00
```

Renaming days and adding linebrakes is not a problem, but how to add hours for each day in the group?

I did only this thing: `str_replace('0,', '0<br>', $opening_hours)`, I have no idea what else should be done to make required format of this text.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: I did only this thing: str_replace('0,', '0<br>', $opening_hours),
I have no idea what else should be done to make required format of this text. And I'm not sure if it even possible... Sure I can make full names of week days, but it is not a main problem.

Comment: Your Question makes no sense, you didnt define the time for Mo,Tu,We and Th but your example includes the time 12:00-18:00 for those days.

Comment: @Xatenev that what I want to do - to add time for each week day, not to the group of the days.

Comment: http://regexr.com/3dhd9 you can get days w.r.t time range. RegEx: `(([a-zA-Z,]*) [\d]{2}\:[\d]{2}\-[\d]{2}\:[\d]{2})`. Use `preg_match` to get days then you can `explode` with comma.

Comment: You can capture them with this: Preg_match_all("/\w+\:\w+|\w+/", $string) I'm at work so I can't finish the code but from there you can loop through the items and build a new array with the days and times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// test inputs
// $input = 'Mo,Tu 05:30-22:00, We,Th 06:00-22:00, Fr 06:00-20:00, Sa, Su 10:00-17:30';
// $input = 'Mo 8-18,Tu 8-18, We 8-18, Th 8 -18 ,Fr 8-18, Sa 10-16';
// $input = 'Mo ; Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa 012:00-12:00';

$input = 'Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr10:00-21:00,            Sa,Su13:00-19:00';


function parseOpeningHours($input)
{
    // normilize
    $weekdays = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'];

    $weekdayoptions = implode('|', array_unique($weekdays));

    $unwrapped_input = preg_replace_callback('/\b(' . $weekdayoptions . ')-(' . $weekdayoptions . ')/', function ($matches) use ($weekdays) {
        list (, $from, $to) = $matches;

        $from_idx = array_search($from, $weekdays);

        $to_idx = array_search($to, array_slice($weekdays, $from_idx));

        $unwrapped_range = implode(',', array_slice($weekdays, $from_idx, $to_idx + 1));
        return $unwrapped_range;

    }, $input);

    // find time range for each day of the week
    $result = [
        'Mo' => null,
        'Tu' => null,
        'We' => null,
        'Th' => null,
        'Fr' => null,
        'Sa' => null,
        'Su' => null,
    ];
    $offset = 0;
    while (preg_match('/\b(' . $weekdayoptions . ').*?(\d{1,2})(?::(\d{1,2}))?\s*-\s*(\d{1,2})(?::(\d{1,2}))?/', $unwrapped_input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {


        @list (, list ($weekday, $offset), list ($from_hh), list ($from_mm), list ($to_hh), list ($to_mm)) = $matches;

        // normalize the time range
        if ($from_mm == '') $from_mm = '00';
        if ($to_mm == '') $to_mm = '00';
        $time_range = "$from_hh:$from_mm-$to_hh:$to_mm";

        $result[$weekday] = $time_range;
        $offset += strlen($weekday);
    }

    return $result;
}

var_dump(parseOpeningHours($input));
```

test output:

```
xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx:~/xxxxxxxxx$ php test.php 
/xxxxxxxxx/test.php:55:
array(7) {
  'Mo' =>
  string(11) "10:00-21:00"
  'Tu' =>
  string(11) "10:00-21:00"
  'We' =>
  string(11) "10:00-21:00"
  'Th' =>
  string(11) "10:00-21:00"
  'Fr' =>
  string(11) "10:00-21:00"
  'Sa' =>
  string(11) "13:00-19:00"
  'Su' =>
  string(11) "13:00-19:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stringToParse = "Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 12:00-18:00, Sa 12:00-16:00";
$dayTimeArray = explode( ',', $stringToParse );

$niceWeekDays = array( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday');
$niceWeekendDay = array('Saturday');

foreach ( $dayTimeArray as $dayTime ) {
    $dayTime = trim( $dayTime );
    if ( strstr( $dayTime, 'Fr' ) ) {
        $singleDayTimeArray = explode( ' ', $dayTime );
        $timeForWeekDays = $singleDayTimeArray[1];
    }

    if ( strstr( $dayTime, 'Sa' ) ) {
        $singleDayTimeArray = explode( ' ', $dayTime );
        $timeForWeekendDays = $singleDayTimeArray[1];
    }
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ( $niceWeekDays as $weekDay ) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $weekDay . '</td><td>' . $timeForWeekDays . '</td></tr>';
}

foreach ( $niceWeekendDay as $weekendDay ) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $weekendDay . '</td><td>' . $timeForWeekendDays . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

This works but it's only usable for the string you've given. There's probably a much smarter way of going about this, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?php
$a1='Mo,Tu,We,Th,Fr 12:00-18:00, Sa 12:00-16:00';

$fridayArr = explode ('Fr ', $a1);
$fridayArr = explode(',', $fridayArr[1]);

$dayNames = array(0=>'Sunday', 1=>'Monday', 2=>'Tuesday', 3=>'Wednesday', 4=>'Thursday', 5=>'Friday', 6=>'Saturday');

$token = strtok($a1, ",");
$i = 1;
$div = '';

while ($token !== false)
   {

if($i<=5) {
   $div .= "$dayNames[$i]  $fridayArr[0]<br>";
} else {
  $div .= str_ireplace('sa', $dayNames[$i], $token) . "<br>";
}

$token = strtok(",");
$i++;
   }
echo $div;
```

Answer (score 1):

These functions might help you, but note, that they assume that your last element in the input will contain an interval:

```
function getNiceDay($day) {
    switch ($day) {
        case 'Mo': return 'Monday';
        case 'Tu': return 'Tuesday';
        case 'We': return 'Wednesday';
        case 'Th': return 'Thursday';
        case 'Fr': return 'Friday';
        case 'Sa': return 'Saturday';
        case 'Su': return 'Sunday';
    }
}

function convertToStringArray($input) {
    $returnValue = array();
    $days = explode(",", $input);
    $lastIntervalIndex = -1;
    foreach ($index = 0; $index < count($days); $index++) {
        $day = trim($days[$index]);
        $days[$index] = getNiceDay(substr($day, 0, 2));
        if (strlen($day) > 2) {
            $interval = substr($day, strrpos($day, " "));
            for ($intervalIndex = $lastIntervalIndex; $intervalIndex <= $index; $intervalIndex++) {
                $days[$intervalIndex] .= $interval;
            }
            $lastIntervalIndex = $index;
        }
    }
    return $days;
}
```